# Coercive bilinear form as solution to minimization problem

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, bilinear-form

Let $a(u,v)=\int_0^1 u'v'+\left( \int_0^1 u\right)\left( \int_0^1 v\right)$ be a bilinear form defined on $H^1(0,1)$.
Show that for every $f \in L^2$ there exists a unique $u \in H^1$ such that
\begin{align}
\left( \forall v \in H^1 \right) a(u,v)=\int_0^1 fv.
\end{align}
My guess is that one should use the fact that $a$ is coercive in some way...

This should also correspond to a certain minimization problem.

Comment: This is [Lax-Miligram Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lions%E2%80%93Lax%E2%80%93Milgram_theorem)